# Query parameters do not update in the URL after a state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-state, react-state-management

I have a React/Next.js application in which I want to create my URL dynamically.

Currently, however, this URL is not updated within my `useEffect` hook when the state changes.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my `useEffect`:

```
export const MyStuffContainer = ({
  url,
  selectedStuff,
}: MyStuffContainerInterface) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useQuery();

  useEffect(() => {
    const tmp = { ...query };
    const querystring = getQString(tmp);
    const newUrl =
      getQStringForSelectedStuff(selectedStuff) !== '' && querystring !== ''
        ? url + '?' + querystring + '&' + getQStringForSelectedStuff(selectedStuff)
        : url + '?' + querystring;
  }, [selectedStuff]);

...
}
```

This is the `getQString` method used within my `useEffect`:

```
const getQString = (parameter) => {
    const qString = [];
    for (const p in parameter) {
      qString.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(parameter[p]));
    }
    return qString.join('&');
};
```

This is the `getQStringForSelectedStuff` method used within my `useEffect`:

```
const getQStringForSelectedStuff = (parameter) => {
    const qStringWithSelectedStuff = [];

    params.forEach((parameter) => {
      qStringWithSelectedStuff.push('project=' + encodeURIComponent(parameter.id));
    });

    return qStringWithSelectedStuff.join('&');
};
```

Here is the code above in one piece:

```
export const MyStuffContainer = ({
  url,
  selectedStuff,
}: MyStuffContainerInterface) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useQuery();


  const getQString = (parameter) => {
    const qString = [];
    for (const p in parameter) {
      qString.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(parameter[p]));
    }
    return qString.join('&');
  };

  const getQStringForSelectedStuff = (parameter) => {
    const qStringWithSelectedStuff = [];

    params.forEach((parameter) => {
      qStringWithSelectedStuff.push('project=' + encodeURIComponent(parameter.id));
    });

    return qStringWithSelectedStuff.join('&');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const tmp = { ...query };
    const querystring = getQString(tmp);
    const newUrl =
      getQStringForSelectedStuff(selectedStuff) !== '' && querystring !== ''
        ? url + '?' + querystring + '&' + getQStringForSelectedStuff(selectedStuff)
        : url + '?' + querystring;
  }, [selectedStuff]);

}
```

**One more info:** `selectedStuff` that comes in via the props is updated correctly.

Here are examples of how I want my URL to be:

Initial state:

--> `http://localhost:8080/my-app/my-stuff`

If the condition `getQStringForSelectedStuff(selectedStuff) !== '' && querystring !== ''` is false (so only `queryString !== ''` is true)

--> `http://localhost:8080/my-app/my-stuff?id=testId&label=testLabel&Stuff=dummyStuff_123`

If the condition `getQStringForSelectedStuff(selectedStuff) !== '' && querystring !== ''` is true

--> `http://localhost:8080/my-app/my-stuff?id=testId&label=testLabel&Stuff=dummyStuff_123&project=dummyProject_123`

If I now deselect `dummyProject_123`, then the URL should be updated so that `&project=dummyProject_123` is removed again. The `selectedStuff` array is right after deselecting, but it doesn't affect the URL.

Comment: You never call the `setQuery` function. Assuming this hook also updates the URL when calling this function.

Comment: The setQuery function is called within another useEffect. I've simplified the code above, otherwise its very complex to show here..

Comment: @Codehan25 Can you post the code where you call the `setQuery` method?